# How do I enable *all* keys on the touchscreen keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, touchscreen

Don't get me wrong, I'm grateful that we *have* a touchscreen keyboard.

All the good keys are there for normal language...

[image: Touchscreen keyboard in 19.04 alphabet keys]

Keys are there to get into `vim` command mode....*

[image: Touchscreen keyboard in 19.04 symbol keys]

And I can write my `bash` scripts in emoji!

[image: Touchscreen keyboard in 19.04 emoji keys]

But wait, now I'm ***stuck***!

How do I:

- ESC (escape current mode in vi??) Can't get back my work!!
- CTRL (I can't CTRL+Z to jump back to the same shell)
- ARROW KEYS (How am I ever going to play Kings Quest on DosBox now???)

:-(

:-p

*(Please excuse the hidden joke if you try this.)

Answer (score 2):

The GNOME On Screen Keyboard (OSK) is designed to [generate keyboards](https://blogs.gnome.org/carlosg/2017/12/07/osk-update/) from the Unicode [Common Locale Data Repository data](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/keyboards/layouts/en.html). The Unicode CLDR was never intended to limit the keys available, but that seems to be the path the GNOME developers are following. If a key isn't in the CLDR, there is no way to type it. So, that means, no `Esc`, no `F1`, no `Control`, etc.

Theoretically, you can install [caribou antler](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Caribou/NewLayout) and customize your own keyboards. However, it didn't work for me and I resorted to [xvkbd](http://t-sato.in.coocan.jp/xvkbd/) which is hoary and ugly but gets the job done. (Tip: If your window manager loses focus when you click in xvkbd, use the Focus button to pick which window to type into.)